# Formatting data with python

Tags: python, formatting

Hi guys i have this file, and i need to clean it, not sure where to start

```
['GB', 'LINCOLN'] ['GB;ENG;Lincoln\n'] 3396
(['IT', 'SEGRATE'], "IT~25~Segrate'\n", 3397)
(['IT', 'SEGRATE'], "IT~25~Segrate'\n", 3398)
(['MX', 'IZTAPALAPA', 'CIUDAD DE MEXICO'], "MX~CMX~Iztapalapa'\n", 3399)
(['US', 'VA', 'CHESAPEAKE'], "US~VA~Chesapeake'\n", 3400)
(['US', 'GA', 'UNION CITY'], "US~GA~Union City'\n", 3401)
['GB', 'HULL'] ['GB;ENG;Sutton', 'on', 'Hull\n'] 3402
```

Ideally what i am looking to output is a csv file.

```
GB,LINCOLN,GB,ENG,Lincoln
MX,IZTAPALAPA,CIUDAD DE MEXICO,MX,CMX,Iztapalapa
```

This file as extremely inconsistent data, so i am not sure how am i going to do this.

I am not a programmer, so i am kind of struggling here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to do the job:

```
with open("filetoopen.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


no = ['[',']','(',')','\'','\"',' ']
com = [';','~']
li = []

for i in range(len(lines)):
    for j in range(len(lines[i])):
        if lines[i][j] == '\\':
            break
        elif lines[i][j] in com:
            li.append(',')
        elif lines[i][j] not in no and lines[i][j] not in com:
            li.append(lines[i][j])            
    li.append("\n")
li.pop()

ans = ''.join(li)

with open("mycsv.csv", "w") as g:
    g.write(ans)
f.close()
g.close()
```